# Children are children. Is this sentence correct?

Tags: sentence

Is the following sentence grammatically correct in formal writing? 
'Children are children'. Wrote this in IELTS examination as a opening sentence for an essay. Curious enough to know before results are out.

Comment: @54696D Correct in what sense? *Lambs green cheese*? *Conch sneeze elbow*?

Comment: "Children will be children" is the more common idiom, but "Children are children" is perfectly fine grammar.

Comment: Your examples are missing verbs, @DanBron.  They need something like *Lambs drive green cheese* or *Conch said sneeze elbow* :-)

Comment: @DanBron _Green_ is not a verb, and _sneeze_ would have to be _sneezes_.  But, in most cases, the nouns would have to be the same.

Comment: @KristinaLopez No, [*to green*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/green_3) is a verb, and *to sneeze* is a verb: the latter is intransitive and can't take a direct object and therefore the sentence is ungrammatical; the former is transitive, and so the sentence is grammatical but nonsensical. Both examples match the pattern "noun verb noun", but either can be considered "not correct" in some way. This is contradiction to 54 69 6D's assertion, therefore that assertion does not hold water.

Comment: So, all we need to ask is if the sentence 'Children are children' is considered nonsensical.

Comment: @54696D Even if your assertion about verb agreement were correct (in this case, it isn't, because *conch* can be used as a mass noun), it contradicts your earlier assertion that "*any* `noun verb noun` sentence is correct", as does you qualification that "in most cases, the nouns would have to be the same". All I'm doing here is disabusing OP and any who come after him of that (incorrect) notion. Even the more limited `N0 v N0` (where N0 is some fixed noun) is incorrect: again, *v* may be intransitive.

Comment: @DanBron, nice try but the present version of sneeze is the least common and doesn't work well in your rebuttal example, nor does "green" as a verb...at least without "up".  Thanks for making me have to look up my own remark to defend it though. ;-)

Comment: Alright, my original comment is incorrect (or at least misleading.)  I will delete it.

Comment: We really have to weaken your assertion to "`N0 copula N0` is correct so long as the copula is correctly inflected", but that rule is hardly more useful than saying "yes OP, *children are children* is correct".

Comment: @KristinaLopez I don't understand your rebuttal. Both *sneeze* and *green* (alone, i.e. not phrasal verbs like "green up") are incontestably verbs and both provide counterexamples to the (spurious) "rule" that *any `noun verb noun` sentence is correct*. They are *intended* to produce absurd results! The specific reasons, whether it be the "present version of sneeze is the least common" (it's actually because the sentence attempts to use it transitively) or that "green doesn't work without up" (it does, just not in this example, which is the point) are *immaterial*. They're *counterexamples*.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Ah, I see, 54 69 6D has deleted his original comment in response to my criticism. So what's going on here is that you were responding to me as if I were addressing the OP, and I was responding to you as if you were aware I was critiquing 54 69 6D's (specious) assertion. That clears it up.

Comment: Yes, it is.  You can say, "Children are children."  There is nothing ungrammatical about that.  It's a simple declarative sentence in which the subject and the predicate nominative are the same.  Moreover, I can even imagine scenarios in which it would be meaningful.  It would tend to remind the reader of the nature of children, that children behave like children, that we cannot expect children to be anything different or more than they are (Example:  "Kids are kids.  They push boundaries.  That's what kids do.").

Comment: I wrote 'Children are children' as a opening sentence for an essay titled 'Should children choose free time activities themselves or others must choose for them?' Wanted to know how far the sentence's context is correct to express what l meant to say. Now I'm sure, in what sense the sentence is taken.

Answer (score 4):

Sentences of the form "Something is something", where both instances of "something" are replaced by "money", "food", or any other everyday object, is something of an idiom meaning that the named object is mundane and instances of it are, in some sense, interchangeable.

"Something will be something", with "something" replaced, eg, with "children", "politicians", "neighbors", et al, is a somewhat different idiom meaning that the named individuals will tend behave in a fashion consistent with their ilk, whatever that may imply.

In particular, "Children will be children" is sometimes applied to adults behaving in what is perceived to be a childish fashion.